# Django annotate according to foreign field's attribute

Tags: django, model

I normally use something like this "Tag.object.annotate(num_post=Count('post')).filter(num_post__gt=2)" to get tags with more than 2 posts. I want to get number of posts with a field value (e.g post.published=True) and annote over them so that I get tags with number of published posts bigger than some value. How would I do that?

### Edit:

What I want is not filter over annotated objects. What I want is something like this: Tag.objects.annotate(num_post=Count("posts that have published field set to true!")). What I am trying to learn is, how to put post that have published field set to true in Count function.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the 2 in `..._gt=2` with some other variable - for example, a variable that gets passed into the view, or a request.GET value, or similar.

Is that what you're trying to do?